# Firebase rules without Firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I know this is a duplicate question but none of them helped me

I use Firestore for storing little amount of data... which will be deleted after some minutes which contains no personal information. I have my own authentication system for logging users in. The users have read and write permission in the Firestore. The problem is application is in production and I keep getting Firebase warning mail that '*Your Cloud Firestore database has insecure rules*'.

i have published Firebase rule as

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I have gone through many reference and I figured it out that for secure data we have to you it's own authentication. or is there any solution for it..?

Comment: These rules give EVERYONE read/write access to your application, even the ones that you have not authenticated via you "authentication system". Anyone (me for instance) can just go and delete everything and add whatever data he/she wants. Is that what you want?

Comment: If you are not using Firebase Authentication, then there is no solution.  That is the only way to get security per-user auth with security rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using Firebase Authentication, then there is no solution for secure per-user access.  If you have a different auth system, you will have to integrate Firebase into that using a [custom auth provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth).

Answer (score 0):

If you have to allow users to read-write with security rules. You can use the cloud function. Cloud function has administrative access. It bypassing the security rules. You have to create Rest API for Firestore read-write operation. Cloud functions doest not require user authentication.